# d not being set with expected information

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a simple svg pie chart with d3.

Here's the code that generates the pie chart and the data set:

```
/* data */
var pieLayout = d3.layout.pie();
var pieData = pieLayout([21, 32, 35, 64, 83]);
/* generator */
var pieGenerator = d3.svg.arc()
                     .innerRadius(20)
                     .outerRadius(50)
                     .startAngle( function(d){ 
                        console.log(d) 
                        return d.startAngle }
                      )
                     .endAngle( function(d){ 
                        console.log(d)
                        return d.endAngle
                      });
/* usage */
svg.append('path').data(pieData).attr('d', pieGenerator)
```

**For whatever reason, I just get one segment of my pie chart appearing. Why is this?**

See those `console.log`s inside the `.startAngle` function and the `.endAngle` function? They just log the first object inside `pieData`:

```
Object {data: 21, value: 21, startAngle: 5.721709173346517, endAngle: 6.283185307179587} (index):189
Object {data: 21, value: 21, startAngle: 5.721709173346517, endAngle: 6.283185307179587}
```

How do I get it to loop through **all** of the objects in `pieData`, and not just the first one?

I tried using `datum` instead of `data`, but that just made `d` equal to `pieData` for each loop. Here's the console.log that reflects using datum:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNA50,50 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA20,20 0 1,0 NaN,NaNZ"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the D3 select...data pattern correctly. You're appending just a single element and binding data to it instead of

```
svg.selectAll("path").data(pieData)
   .enter().append('path').attr('d', pieGenerator)
```

See e.g. [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) for more information on the general pattern.

Comment: Great! Feels a bit weird though, selecting a path that doesn't exist, giving this non existent selector data, entering it and only then appending the path...anyway, works now, thanks